# beautifulsoup html parser for words outside tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use `beautifulsoup` html parser to parse some texts within and outiside tags, but I get strange formatting especially with words outside any of the tags. THe texts are inside a dictionary and looks like this:

```
([('<tag1>London</tag1>in<tag2>UK</tag2>', 'Locations')])

 for key, value in s.iteritems():
     soup = BeautifulSoup(key, 'html.parser')
     print soup.text

 >LondoninUK
```

but I noticed that if I introduce a space before and after `in`, for example
`<tag1>London</tag1> in <tag2>UK</tag2>, Locations`  it parses it correctly `London in UK` 
How can I rectify this, instead of having to manually add space in between words outside tags?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

for key, value in s.iteritems():
    soup = BeautifulSoup(key)
    print soup.getText(' ')
```

Adding execution:

```
>>> s = '<tag1>London</tag1> in <tag2>UK</tag2>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
>>> soup.getText(' ')
u'London in UK'
>>> s = '<tag1>London</tag1>in<tag2>UK</tag2>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
>>> soup.getText(' ')
u'London in UK'
>>>
```

Where does it add spaces?

Comment: but its also adding an extra space..I got `London  in  UK`

Comment: @DevEx, if you look at the BeautifulSoup source code, you'll see that `tag.text` is a `@property` that calls `tag.getText('')`. The argument to `tag.getText` is the white-space replacement string, so calling `tag.text` by default, gives you no spaces between text. Look more closely at the answer.

Comment: @user3432110 I'm getting extra spaces where there are spaces inside the elements of the tags e.g. ´s = <tag1>London </tag1>´ How can I strip off spaces inside the elements of tags i.e.´<tag1>London </tag1>´ becomes ´<tag1>London</tag1>´ ?

Comment: U want the entire tag with space stripped or the content of the tags?